# CSS conflict bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a website for an event, then I've added a countdown to it, but my footer and the button above it, are behaving differently in the page where the countdown is present.

I've come up with this:

the countdown is good as far as it's connected to a Bootstrap CSS;
That Bootstrap CSS makes my footer and button change aspect;
My question is: **how do I make the countdown stay and work with the footer and button aspect unchanged?**

This is the page of the website which doesn't work: http://goo.gl/mH9nLh

And this is the one which works: 
http://goo.gl/24SZxQ

I'm not linking you the code 'cause I don't know where the error is, this way you'll be able to see each part of code and mostly: what should I take from that Bootstrap css file or some other tricks to get around the problem.

If you need anything please don't ignore this question, rather leave a comment I'll text back instantly!

Comment: bootstrap using font size :14px; & your css using 19pt

Comment: What should that solve sorry @LaljiTadhani

Comment: Add `text-align:center` in your `#footer`.

Comment: Yeah @Alorika , but the problem is also that the Bootstrap CSS changes the aspect (design) of the footer and of the button

Comment: your custom css body {
    color: #888;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro",sans-serif;
    font-size: 19pt;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.75em;
}

Comment: Add link to "main.css" stylesheet in head tag after the bootstap css link

Comment: bootstrap body {
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
}

Comment: @ArunKumarM gonna do it

Comment: @LaljiTadhani trying now!

Comment: @LaljiTadhani yikes it works! Now I've also centered the text @Alorika! Would you guys please check it again and see how I can activate the button slide animation that you can see in action in the second link?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the 2 links you pasted above.
There is a main.css file which is included in the [second link](http://goo.gl/24SZxQ) , which has styles for the table and it's subsequent child classes.
The same is not available in the [first link](http://goo.gl/mH9nLh) and this is the reason you are seeing 2 different styles.

Please include the same set of css files in both the pages so that I can better debug the possible problem areas.

Comment: Thanks for checking that out Rahul, look, we've added the main in the first link and edited those few things that the others told us to edit and we're just fine. Although we now have 2 little problems: 1 the button doesn't scroll up with the animation as it does in the second link 2 The countdown isn't visible (probably under the main page)

Comment: Hi,
You have not included main.js file.
It contains $('.scrolly').scrolly(); which is used to add the scroll effect

Comment: You need the JavaScript?

Comment: Open the console in your chrome and write $('.scrolly').scrolly();
You will see the button grabs that scroll effect immediately.

Thus including the main.js should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try later and let you know

Comment: Now if I can ask, what do you think I should do to solve the problem of the countdown not in position?